# Requisição ajax não declara session

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho um sistema de login com Ajax+PHP com as linguagens rodando em servidores diferentes. No mesmo servidor funciona perfeitamente, mas nesse modo, a requisição ocorre mas a session não é declarada (eu preciso que ela seja declarada apenas no servidor remoto, não preciso passar ela para o servidor local, apenas das páginas geradas pelo próprio servidor remoto com base nas sessions). O Cors está autorizado pela `Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` (em caráter de teste) e creio que esteja funcionando pois quando a senha é incorreta, por exemplo, ela retorna o que deveria, mas não declara a session.

Código da requisição para o servidor

```
<script>

$('document').ready(function(){
 
    $("#btn-login").click(function(){
        var data = $("#login-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'urldoservidorremoto/login.php',
            data : data,
            success :  function(response){                      
                if(response == "1"){    
                    $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'none');
                    window.location.href = "login-confirma.html";
                }
                else{
                    $("#btn-login").html('Entrar');
                    $("#login-alert").css('display', 'block')
                    $("#mensagem").html('Email ou senha incorretos. Tente novamente!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
 
});

</script>
```

Código do php - Executado remotamente

```
<?php

include 'db.php';
 
$email = $_POST["email"];
$senha = sha1($_POST["senha"]);

//$verifica_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");

$verifica_user = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' and senha = '$senha' ");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($verifica_user);

if($row <= 0){
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
    unset($_SESSION['senha']);
                $retorno = '0';
}
else{
    while($row = $verifica_user->fetch_assoc()) {
            session_start();
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $row["nome"];
                $_SESSION['sobrenome'] = $row["sobrenome"];
                $_SESSION['nascimento'] = $row["nascimento"];
                $retorno = '1';
}
    
    $_SESSION['sair'] = 'Sair';
}
    echo $retorno;

?>
```

Eu também fiz um login.js executado remotamente para verificar se a pessoa está logada, esse login.js roda remotamente, eu liberei que ele seja gerado por php no mysql.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $verifica_user = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($verifica_user);
    while($row = $verifica_user->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ativado = $row["contaativa"];
    $endereco = $row["endereco"];
    if($ativado==0){
    echo "var contaativa = 'inativo'; \n ";
    echo "var endereco = 'ativo'; \n ";
    echo "var logado = 'ativo'";
    }elseif($endereco==0){
    echo "var endereco = 'inativo'; \n ";
    echo "var contaativa = 'ativo'; \n ";
    echo "var logado = 'ativo'";

    }else{
    echo "var endereco = 'ativo'; \n ";
    echo "var contaativa = 'ativo'; \n ";
    echo "var logado = 'ativo'";
    }
    }
}else{
    echo "var logado = 'inativo'";
}
?>
```

Essa é a parte que verifica localmente

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="urldoservidoremoto/js/login.js"></script>
<script>
if(logado == 'inativo'){
    window.location.href = 'login.html';
}
else if(contaativa == 'inativo'){
    window.location.href = 'ativarconta.html';
}else if(endereco == 'inativo'){
    window.location.href = 'configuraendereco.html';
}
</script>
```

Existe alguma forma de liberar da session funcionar no servidor e os retornos do ajax sejam gerados de acordo com ela? Só reiterando: No servidor local, tudo funciona normalmente.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você precisa da session rodando apenas no servidor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

Inseri `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},` na requisição ajax e `Header Set Access Control-Allow-Credentials: true` no meu .htaccess do servidor remoto, sem esquecer do `Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'http://urldoservidor'`, que eu já tinha antes.